# "dizer" and "falar" are often interchangeable. Are there any rules or clues about when they are not?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, diferenças

In the spoken language, verbs **"falar" and "dizer"** are often interchangeable. There are situations when they are not, though. **Is there any rule of thumb about this to help those who are learning portuguese?**

e.g. **In ptBR there isn't much difference, if any, between:**

- fale a verdade, diga a verdade
- falou que vinha, disse que vinha
- fale o motivo, diga o motivo
- falando asneiras, dizendo asneiras

Then again, we can only use one of them in sentences like: **"Ela fala Alemão"**, **"Os senhores estão falando muito alto"**, **"O padre estava a dizer a missa".**

Of course there are several fixed-phrases and idioms with both words, but **these are not the subject of this question:** e.g.

- "falou!" (ok, brother),
- "falar grosso" (not to look or sound afraid), -
- "falar mais alto" (speak louder),
- "por assim dizer" (so to speak),
- "não dizer ao que veio" (not to show what he/she/it is here for)

**EDIT - EM PORTUGUÊS**  "dizer" e "falar" frequentemente tem o mesmo significado no português falado e podem ser usados indistintamente. "falar ou dizer a verdade", "falar ou dizer o que pensa", etc.  Existe alguma regra ou dica a respeito de quando apenas um deles pode ser usado?

EDIT 2 - I've just read in a comment that such interchangeability does not occur in ptPT. If that is the case, this question refers to ptBR only.

Comment: Isto devia estar marcado pt-BR, porque em Portugal a diferença é  muito mais marcada: em geral, "dizer" usa-se nas circunstâncias em que em inglês se usa "say" e "tell" e "falar" naquelas em que se usa "talk" e "speak" (nos usos mais comuns). "falou que vinha", "fale o motivo" e "falando asneiras" muito dificilmente se usariam em Portugal. A única admissível será "fale a verdade" e isso talvez porque "falar verdade" parece uma expressão fixa.

Comment: @Artefacto OK,  Está marcado.  Coloquei em negrito para chamar mais a atenção de quem lê.

Comment: @Centaurus I have the same impression as Artefacto does, that only *falar a verdade* works for me, but I don't know if I'm just calqing from Spanish or even English in so doing. [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/falar) and [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dizer--falar/7465) are not as completely clear on this as I would like, which is why this is just a comment not an answer.

Comment: @tchrist Talvez a gente deva culpar o Garret: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falar_Verdade_a_Mentir :p

Comment: Será que é a mesma coisa com ouvir/escutar... (?)

Answer (score 7):

I would say that, as a general rule of thumb in European Portuguese, **say** and **tell** coalesce to **dizer** whereas **talk** and **speak** to **falar**.

Thus *tell the truth* becomes *dizer a verdade*, *she said hello* becomes *ela disse olá*, *I speak Portuguese* becomes *eu falo português*, and *talk to me* becomes *fala comigo*.

Comment: Would you say that in general, in Portugal it is normally *dizer-lhe uma coisa* and not *falar-lhe uma coisa*? I ask because Centaurus’s example from Brazil of *falar o motivo* sounds odd to my non-native ear. It doesn’t seem to be a match for *falar a verdade*, but I do not know why not.

Comment: In Portugal it would sound strange to say *falar o motivo*. We would undoubtedly always say *dizer o motivo*.

Comment: And _talk to me_ becomes _fala comigo_. Podes acrescentar. _Talk_ generally becomes _falar_.

Comment: That's absolutely right, I'll correct the answer

Comment: I would like to make sure you all understand my question is about the use of "dizer" and "falar" in the spoken language.

Comment: The distinctions referred to here are the same both for the spoken and written language.

Comment: @tchrist I, myself, would say "dizer o motivo".  The examples I've given is what you hear in the streets.